# Recursion, and the difference between -- and i-1

Tags: c#, recursion

I was doing some C# practice and decided to make a basic function to sum the contents of an integer array.

Originally I wrote my code as follows:

```
if(index == 0)
   return toSum[index];
else 
   return toSum[index] + sum(toSum, index--);
```

Now that code resulted in a StackOverFlow exception. This made no sense to me; surely this is how one would do a summation? Turns out the problem was in the `index--`. When I changed it to `index - 1` it worked out fine, thus I was wondering why is that the case? My understanding is that it is simply a shorthand for `index = index-1`. I was wondering if anyone could explain the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: How did you check your understanding of what `index--` means? Did you look at a book or C# reference?

Comment: `--index` would be a shorthand for `index = index - 1`, but if there’s no point in changing the variable, why do it?

Comment: Mostly going by what I recalled from the way they taught us about it in my freshman year programming class. It was in Java though as I trying to self-teach myself C#. My understanding for the longest of time was that index--, is short hand for index = index-1;

Comment: (This operator works the same in C# and Java, note.)

Comment: I think it just clicked, @Ryan. Since with a recursive call I guess you need --index since if the decrement is after it will never decrement correct? If I changed index-- to --index the function returns the correct result instead of overflowing.

Comment: @SomeStudent: It’s not specifically about the recursion, just about the value you want. If index is 5, you want to pass 4 to the next `sum` call. You can get that value using `index - 1` or `--index` or `index -= 1` or `-(-index + 1)` or `index-- - 1`, but the first way is the only one that really makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post-decrement operator returns the value before decrementing, so in your case the index will never be 0 and the function won't stop calling itself and you'll get a stack overflow. You want to write `--index` instead. It will return the value after decrementing then.